# Delete function in circular linked list changing next and previous to null when only one node left

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

In my delete function for a circular doubly linked list when I enter the function with two nodes and delete one node it is changing my next node and previous node to null.  This only happens when I enter the function with two nodes in the linked list.  I am using breakpoints in eclipse and everything seems to be working until I end the function and return the temp.  After that the next and previous for ptrLocal get set to NULL. Not really sure why.

Here is the function call

```
struct TCB_t del = delete_from_list(&RunQ);
```

Here is the function

```
struct TCB_t delete_from_list(struct  TCB_t **ptrLocal)
{
    struct TCB_t temp;

    if(*ptrLocal)
    {

        temp = **ptrLocal;
        temp.next = NULL;
        temp.previous =NULL;

        if(*ptrLocal == (*ptrLocal)->next->next)
        {
            *ptrLocal = (*ptrLocal)->next;
            (*ptrLocal)->next = *ptrLocal;
            (*ptrLocal)->previous =  *ptrLocal;
        }
        else if(*ptrLocal != (*ptrLocal)->next)
        {
            (*ptrLocal)->previous->next = (*ptrLocal)->next;
            (*ptrLocal)->next->previous = (*ptrLocal)->previous;
            *ptrLocal = (*ptrLocal)->next;
        }
        else
        {
            (*ptrLocal)->previous = NULL;
            (*ptrLocal)->next = NULL;
            *ptrLocal =NULL;
        }
        count--;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

After return temp ptrLocal->next and preLocal->previous are both set to null.

Comment: Do you ever malloc or free items?  What do you do with the return value of the function?  I don't see a problem (yet), but I think it is strange for you to return a copy of the deleted item because the actual item deleted will be leaked if you originally malloc'd it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is the last else. it applied when there is single node in the list.

In Circular linked list, next and previuos never shouldn't be NULL

Therefor if there is only 1 item, next and previous should point to itself.

Now your you should check like this:

```
if ((*ptrLocal)->next = (*ptrLocal)){ //delete the last item in the list, should NULL the pointer
   free(*ptrLocal); 
   *ptrLocal=NULL;   
}
else {
   (*ptrLocal)->previous->next = temp->next;
   (*ptrLocal)->next->previous = temp->previous;
   free(*ptrLocal);
}
```

I don't see the reason to check for two items:

For example A<->B<->A

And you delete B:

if you go to the else: you get A<->A which is still a circular list.

Comment: Thanks, but now free(*ptrLocal) under the if statement is causing a double free or corruption(out) error.  The second  free(*ptrLocal) does not cause the errot

Comment: if you free the pointer elsewhere don't free it in the `delete_from_list`. I think the right place to free is in the function, otherwise why is the return?